# Magento - DB error with product extension

Tags: magento

I have installed this extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16917/

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mysite_testsite2`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) O)
```

Any ideas how I would go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

try looking file under folder app/code/[local or community]/[companyname]/[modulename]/sql/[modulename]_setup/mysql4-install-x.x.x.php

what you do is just fix the create table sql...

good luck :D